# Using IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ds get the key, value pair

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I am having a return type of a function being set to `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>` and I need to get the key, value pairs.

Using the appropriate key, I need to change the value.

I have a solution when the return type is a Dictionary but not when `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>`

I finally need to modify the value after, the specific key is found.

Comment: Can multiple dictionaries have the same key? Where do you want to store the changed value? Change the returned dictionaries in place?

Comment: So... your return type is a collection of collections of key-value pair collection?

Comment: @ Lucas I only have on dictionary and I need to modify a value. I was thinking of finding the value using the key and there by modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These following solutions maybe what your looking for, However you'll have to work out which one is more appropriate based on your circumstances

Given

```
var myKey = "someKey";
```

Assuming, your list of dictionaries contains the key your looking for, only once

```
var aDictionary = MyEnumerable.Single(x => x.ContainsKey(myKey));
aDictionary[myKey] = myNewValue;
```

An InvalidOperationException will be thrown if

- More than one key is found
- No keys are found

---

Assuming your list of dictionaries may or may not contain the key your looking for, only once

```
var aDictionary = MyEnumerable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContainsKey(myKey));

if(aDictionary != null)
{
    aDictionary[myKey] = myNewValue;
}
```

An InvalidOperationException will be thrown if

- More than one key is found

---

Assuming there may be multiple occurrences of your key

```
foreach (var aDictionary in MyEnumerable.Where(x => x.ContainsKey(myKey)))
{
    aDictionary[myKey] = myNewValue;
}
```

---

**Update**

It seems you might be confused with the type `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>`

`IEnumerable` is a list (for the point of this conversation)

A `Dictionary` represents a collection of keys and values.

So what you have is a list of collections of keys and values

Comment: What is myobect in this context

Comment: Its the value as denoted by Dictionary<string, object>

Comment: @ saruman can I  get the value from the item using foreach as I have more than one occurrence.

Comment: The third example loops over all the dictionaries that contain your key, and assigns a new value to your KeyValue Pair

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the IEnumerable> using a foreach sentence:
(this is just an example to help to illustrate)

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> colectionDict;
foreach(var dict in colectionDict) //dict is an object of type Dictionary<string,object>
```

Also, you can use a variable type Enumerator.

```
var enum = colectionDict.GetEnumerator();
while(enum.Next){
    var dict = enum.Current; // dict is an object of type Dictionary<string,object>
}
```